# Calculating discounted prices of products in a list

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

What I'm trying to achieve is essentially calculate the total of a list of products that contain discount combianations.

I have a List of `DiscountCombination` items which are set out like this:

```
 public class DiscountCombination
    {
        public List<string> ProductCode{ get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Then given a list of Products `List<string>` I want to calculate the total number of times that each of the `DiscountCombination` objects patterns occurs in the product list, while taking into account that the same pattern may occur multiple times so any products used in a combination get removed so that they aren't used again.

A major issue is that I also need to make sure that I check for all possible combinations BEFORE removing anything from the list, since if there's a set of products that appear in multiple patterns eg:

```
var c1 = new DiscountCombination(new List<string>() {"A", "A"}, 20);
var c2 = new DiscountCombination(new List<string>() {"A", "A", "B"}, 50);

var products = new List<string() { "A", "A", "B" };
```

That only the combination with the lowest price gets removed from the product list.
If someone could give me any advice or point me in the direction of any papers I could read I'd be very grateful!